# JSR352 - Error while updating VSAM file using ZFile.update()

Tags: mainframe, zos, jsr352, java-batch

The writer class opens a file (myfile) in mode and looks-up for a record using a key. Once the record is found, an update() is invoked. I get the following exception when the `update()` call is getting executed

```
fupdate() failed; EDC5065I A write system error was detected. (errno2=0xC0500090); errno=65 errno2=0xc0500090 last_op=115 errorCode=0x80060
```

This file is opened in the `"rb,type=record"` mode in `open()` method of the writer and is closed in the `close()` method of the writer.

The error happens when the writer is getting executed for the very first chunk of the job.

***What could be the problem ?***

Comment: Did you try logging the results of calling the individual fields/getters of the [ZFileException](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.80.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZFileException.html) and then looking up the various codes in the [z/OS XL C/C++ Programming Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01)/iodebug.htm

Comment: For record I/O, z/OS XL C/C++ allows only the use of fread() and fwrite() to read and write to files. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbcpx01/hdrec.htm  Could this be the reason

Comment: I believe opening it 'rb' opens it for read-binary.  To do an update you'd need to open it rb+ to get read/write.  Doc for all the modes is here:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/fopen.htm

And there's a VSAM update using ZFile here:  https://github.com/zsystems/java-samples/blob/master/vsam/file/UpdateKsdsRecords.java